# special character "Â" is not work in Linux, converted into "?"

Tags: java, linux, string, special-characters

I consuming an api which is returning String with special characters, so I replace them with blank or some other user readable char.

My code:

```
String text = response;
        if (text != null) {
            text = text.replace("Â", "");
            //same for other special char
        }
```

The above code works fine for windows machine but in Linux "Â" converted into "?", even other all special char converted into "?".
I am using Java, UTF-8 in my HTML.
Please let me know any platform independent solution. Thanks

Comment: Wild guess, but is your project configured to also use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: You simply _assert_ that this is happening without explaining _why you think it's happening_. This behavior is nearly always due to a misconfigured terminal or equivalent output device.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, In all HTML head we have <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-The code is working in windows but not in Linux machine, I didn't get a "misconfigured terminal or equivalent output device" please elaborate

Comment: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` is what HTML declares to use, but does that file is *actually* encoded using UTF-8? Your editor/IDE should be able to tell you which encoding it uses so check that information (if you don't know where it is let us know what editor/IDE are you using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am consuming the REST api, so while getting the output I have to maintain UTF-8 encoding.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((inputStream), standardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I have added standardCharsets.UTF_8